# GitHub Actionsを用いて、コンパイルして、リリースにアップロードしたい

Tags: github, github-actions

pushした際に、Cのソースコードをコンパイルして、リリースにアップロードしたいのですが、エラーが出てしまいます。どのようにすればよいでしょうか？

```
エラー内容
Error: Error: Input required and not supplied: upload_url
```

```c
// ソースコード Sample.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

```yml
# release.yml
name: Compile & Upload Release

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build
        run: gcc Sample.c -o Sample
      - name: Upload assets to the GitHub release draft
        uses: shogo82148/actions-upload-release-asset@v1
        with:
          upload_url: ${{ github.event.inputs.upload_url }}
          asset_path: ./Sample
```

Comment: どのリリースにアップロードしたいのですか？

Comment: どのリリースという質問がわからないのですが、GitHubのReleaseであればとりあえず問題ないです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`github.event.inputs` コンテキストを利用しているので、[ワークフローをマニュアル実行](https://docs.github.com/ja/actions/learn-github-actions/events-that-trigger-workflows#workflow_dispatch) する前提の設定を参考にしているのではないでしょうか。

```yaml
# release.yml
name: Compile & Upload Release

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      upload_url:
        description: "Assets upload URL"
        required: true

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Build
        run: gcc Sample.c -o Sample
      - name: Upload assets to the GitHub release draft
        uses: shogo82148/actions-upload-release-asset@v1
        with:
          upload_url: ${{ github.event.inputs.upload_url }}
          asset_path: ./Sample
```

とすると、 Actions ページに [Run workflow ボタン](https://docs.github.com/ja/actions/managing-workflow-runs/manually-running-a-workflow)が表れます。

[List Releases API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/repos#list-releases) でアセットアップロードURL(`upload_url`)がわかるので、このURLを Run workflow ボタンの "Assets upload URL" 値として設定すればアップロードできます。

動作確認用に作成したリポジトリがあるので参考になれば。

- https://github.com/yukihane/jaso84041
- https://api.github.com/repos/yukihane/jaso84041/releases

  - Assets upload URL として指定するのはこの場合 `https://uploads.github.com/repos/yukihane/jaso84041/releases/55095380/assets`

---

[作者のblog](https://shogo82148.github.io/blog/2020/12/03/github-actions-in-2020/),[公式のREADME](https://github.com/shogo82148/actions-upload-release-asset#readme)には、別のイベントでのアセットアップロード例があります:

- リリース作成時にアセットアップロード
- 特定の命名パターンのタグ作成時にリリース作成を伴ってアセットアップロード

これらの方が実際に行いたいことに近い、ということもあるかもしれません。